# Convergence of $\int _1^{\infty }\:\frac{7+\sin \left(x\right)}{\sqrt{x+2x^3}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I'm trying to find the convergence of the following improper integral

$\int _1^{\infty }\:\frac{7+\sin \left(x\right)}{\sqrt{x+2x^3}}dx$

However, I am stuck because I wanna find the convergence using the integral comparison test and have not a clue which integral I should compare this with since I don't know whether it converging or diverging.

Comment: The key realization is the top is bounded within 6-8 and the bottom you can simplify to the highest part of the sum as the part giving the most significant growth.

Answer (score 4):

For every $x\ge1$, one has
$$
0\le\frac{7+\sin(x)}{\sqrt{x+2x^3}}\le\frac8{\sqrt2x^{3/2}}.
$$
Since the integral
$$
\int_1^\infty\frac8{\sqrt2x^{3/2}}\,dx
$$
converges, then your integral converges too.

Comment: Haven't really thought about that, thank you so much

Comment: You can remove absolute value as the function is positive.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Yes, I missed that. Thank you.